# For some reason the background image on my link bar is not showing

Tags: php, html, css, image, background

I have been working on this for hours and I can't figure it out. At one point for a while I had it displaying the background image properly now it won't work.

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" media="screen"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" media="screen"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" media="screen"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo grid_4 none">
        <img src="images/4seasons.jpg" class="head grid_8 omega none">
        <ul class="links grid_9">
                <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons/home.png"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons/menu.png"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons/about.png"></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><img src="images/icons/contact.png"></li></a>
        </ul>
        <img src="images/icons/bar.gif" class="bar none">
    </div>
</body>
```

I cannot figure out what is up with this but I appreciate any help!
Heres the CSS:

```
.logo {
    float:left;
}
.head {
    margin-top:2%;
}
.bar {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-5%;
}

/*Links*/

.links {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.links li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:0%;
}
.links li:hover {
    background: url("images/icons/bg.png");
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the link for your site?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have an `<a>` as a direct child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` only a `<li>` is valid so change your mark-up to:

```
 <ul class="links grid_9">
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/home.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/menu.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/aboute.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/contact.png"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Actually the problem was that my stylesheet was not in the same folder as my index.php and I had forgotten to make my link "../images..."

Comment: I see .. well my answer still applies as certain browsers (*ahem* IE) will give you trouble having an `<a>` as a direct child of a list :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a:hover for your link. Maybe the "a" element is infront of the "li" element such that it blocks the detection of mousehover.

```
.links li a:hover {
    background: url("images/icons/bg.png");
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

change your html to below:

html

```
<ul class="links grid_9">
  <li class="home"><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li class="menu"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
  <li class="about"><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.links {float:left}
.links li {float:left; list-style-type:none}
.links li a {
    float:left;
    text-indent:-5000px;
    height:20px; /* set your own dimention */
    width:20px; /* set your own dimention */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.links li.home a {background-image:url(images/icons/home.png);}
.links li.menu a {background-image:url(images/icons/menu.png);}
.links li.about a {background-image:url(images/icons/about.png);}
.links li.contact a {background-image:url(images/icons/contact.png);}

.links li a:hover {background: url("images/icons/bg.png");}
```

hope this help you...